# Delete/clear active cron job

Tags: linux, cron

How can I delete or clear all the cron job that I made previously and just run new cron job that I assigned? I'm using `crontab -r` but it just clear in the crontab display, but it still runs that cron job and the previous cron job that I have already deleted by using that code.

After I clear cron job using `crontab -r`, I run `crontab -l` and it shows this output.

```
No crontab for trygcp
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General Linux questions should be posted to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command,

```
crontab -e
```

to access crontab, in there you can deleted specific line or job you created.

About the output you are getting, that only means there is no crontab created under the username *trygcp*

What you can do is this:

```
crontab -u [username] -e
```

Where:

*-u define user*

*-e edit user's crontab*

This command will create a crontab under your username, but remember you must have root privilege for you to do this.